# How to make a group form with two fields inline?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a form with a back ground image. So this form supposed to be responsive. However i'm not able to make it right. How do I place form groups. two in line

Also, how do I make spacing between links in a navigation bar?

```html
<div class="col-sm-4" id="search-block">
<div class="form-group">
<select class="form-control" id="destination-picker">
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
   <option>3</option>
   <option>4</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-inline">
    <form action="/action_page.php">
      <input onfocus="(this.type='date')" class="js-form-control" placeholder="Arrival">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="form-inline">
    <form action="/action_page.php">
      <!-- <input type="date" name="departure"> -->
      <input onfocus="(this.type='date')" class="js-form-control" placeholder="Departure">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="travelers-picker form-inline">
  <div class="form-inline">
    <select class="form-control" id="adult">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Adult</option>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>More</option>
     </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-inline">
      <select class="form-control" id="child">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Child</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>More</option>
       </select>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="button" class="btn-search">START SEARCHING</button>           </div>
</div>
```

#### Form Group example

[image]
[[image: header][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2yI6.png)

Comment: Are you asking about formatting the result like the picture you posted?

Comment: Yes, as it in the picture. So with a flex box I just need to wrap those two elements and thats all?

Comment: Do you use bootstrap? If I look to the div classes it looks like it. Can you also specify which version of bootstrap. And add some css code so other people can see how you added the form background.

Comment: Thanks, guys. I figured out how to do that. I will post the code

Comment: @ultrapanam I saw you resolved this, but i already edited my below post with what you asked...check it out if you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw you're using bootstrap...its pretty easy to format with bootstrap

```css
.giveMargins {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row giveMargins">
    <div class="col-sm-7">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 offset-sm-2">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam rhoncus, ante pretium posuere vestibulum, quam magna sodales velit, in suscipit tellus dolor ut elit.  
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row giveMargins">
        <div class="col-sm-10 offset-sm-2">
          <img src="http://www.nationalgeographic.it/images/2016/12/06/164441083-abc66e5b-8d1b-46d7-a0aa-024b9dea5edb.jpg" 
                  height="200px" width="80%">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <div class="row giveMargins">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control" id="destination-picker">
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
              <option>4</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="form-group">
           <input onfocus="(this.type='date')" class="form-control" placeholder="Arrival">
          </div>
        </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="form-group">
           <input onfocus="(this.type='date')" class="form-control" placeholder="Arrival">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="form-group">
           <select class="form-control" id="adult">
                  <option value="" disabled selected>Adult</option>
                  <option>1</option>
                  <option>2</option>
                  <option>3</option>
                  <option>4</option>
                  <option>More</option>
               </select>
          </div>
        </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="form-group">
           <select class="form-control" id="child">
                  <option value="" disabled selected>Child</option>
                  <option>1</option>
                  <option>2</option>
                  <option>3</option>
                  <option>4</option>
                  <option>More</option>
               </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-search">START SEARCHING</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it works. The only question is how to put it on the right side of the page, I'm trying to edit columns however it doesn't work. It is still like entire block new block

Comment: @ultrapanam you mean to align right the whole container (you see there's margin right and left, thats from the container), or just the columns inside the container?